# Tooltip positioning in table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm using React and have a table with some actions (delete, edit, etc.) in the cell. And I need to put a tooltip on each action. I'm not using the jquery and don't plan to, and not title props (I will need to upgrade this tooltip to some specific data or even another component).

So the problem is I can't position the tooltip correctly (for example in the middle of the top or bottom). Witch params should my component receive and how to do it with css?

```js
const Tooltip = ({position = 'top', display, style, children}) => {
  let displayClass = display ? `fade ${position} in` : `tooltip-${position}`
  return (
    <div className={`tooltip ${displayClass} `} role='tooltip'>
      <div className='tooltip-arrow' />
      <div className='tooltip-inner'>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>

  )
}

const ActionLinkItem = ({page, action, data, onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, display, tooltipText, id}) => {
  const {buttonClass, icon} = actionsStyles[action]
  return (
    <Link to={`/${page}/${action.toLowerCase()}/${data.id}`}>
      <a
        className={`btn btn-xs ${buttonClass}`}
        id={id}
        onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
            ><i className={`fa fa-${icon}`} />
        <Tooltip display={display} action={action}>{tooltipText}</Tooltip>
      </a>
    </Link>
  )
}

export default class Actions extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      tooltipActive: ''
    }
  }

  handleHover (event) {
    this.setState({
      tooltipActive: event.target.id
    })
  }

  handleBlur (event) {
    this.setState({
      tooltipActive: ''
    })
  }

  getActionsTemplate () {
    const {actions, data, page} = this.props
    return actions.map(action => {
      let display = this.state.tooltipActive === `${action.action}-${data.id}`
      let id = `${action.action}-${data.id}`
      let tooltip = tooltipText[action.action].replace(/{type}/g, page).replace(/{item}/g, data.name
      return <ActionLinkItem
            key={`${data.id}-${action.action}`}
            page={page}
            action={action.action}
            data={data}
            id={id}
            tooltipText={tooltip}
            display={display}
            onMouseEnter={(e) => this.handleHover(e)}
            onMouseLeave={(e) => this.handleBlur(e)}
          />    
     })
   }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='row'>
        {this.getActionsTemplate()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest, tooltip should be absolutely positioned within a positioned element.

So, add a style of `position: relative` to the  in ActionLinkItem
and add a style of `position: absolute to the outer  in Tooltip.

For added credit, you will want to set a width on your tooltip, and position or center it within the  of ActionLinkItem using styles like `bottom: 100%`.

You can also do some calculations to ensure that your tooltip does not run off the page by moving it left and right if the containing  is on the right or left respectively.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
the bootstrab tooltip is positioned absolute by default and I have my ActionLinkItem positioned relative. 
but if tooltip has a lot of text it expands my table. I thought I need to set relative higher parent, but then I don't know how to calculate the position.

Comment: my css for tooltip:
`.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1070;
}

.tooltip.fade.in {
    display: flex;
    top: -40px;
    left: -60px;
    bottom: 100%;
}
`